# mysql - rewrite query with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table Users with columns Id, Name, Surname and a table Actions with columns Ip and Actor. I need to retrieve, for every Ip, the set of users who did as action using that Ip.
What I have now looks like:

```
SELECT a.ip, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.id, '-', t.name, ' ', t.surname) FROM(
        SELECT ud.id, ud.name, ud.surname
    FROM users_data AS ud
    JOIN actions AS a2 ON a2.actor = ud.id
    WHERE a2.ip = a.ip
    GROUP BY ud.id) AS t
    )
    FROM actions AS a
WHERE a.ip != '' AND a.ip != '0.0.0.0'
GROUP BY a.ip
```

It doesn't work because a.ip is unknown in the where clause in the inner subquery.

Do to performance issues, I need to avoid to use DISTINCT.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Elmer, shouldn't that be 'wetwieve'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this query (still quite slow, so there's still space for improvements...):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t.ip, COUNT(t.id) AS c, GROUP_CONCAT(t.id, '-', t.name, ' ',   t.surname, '-', t.designerAt > 0) FROM ( 
    SELECT a.ip, ud.id, ud.name, ud.surname, u.designerAt
    FROM actions AS a
    JOIN users_data AS ud ON ud.id = a.actor
    JOIN users AS u ON u.id = a.actor
    WHERE a.ip !=  ''
    AND a.ip !=  '0.0.0.0'
    AND a.actor !=0
    GROUP BY a.ip, a.actor
    ) AS t
GROUP BY t.ip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query as

```
SELECT n.ip, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT n.your_user SEPARATOR ' -- ') `users` FROM
(  
    SELECT a.ip  AS ip, CONCAT(t.id, '-', t.name, ' ', t.surname) `your_user`
    FROM users_data AS ud
    JOIN actions AS a ON a.actor = ud.id         
) `new_table` n
WHERE n.ip != '' AND n.ip != '0.0.0.0'
GROUP BY n.ip
```

> Note Be aware of that the result is truncated to the maximum length
>   that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable, which
>   has a default value of 1024

Comment: doesn't this solution duplicate users? I mean, if a users does more actions on the same Ip, it should anyway apper just one

Comment: @marcosh See my updated answer `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT n.your_user SEPARATOR ' -- ')`

Comment: ok, that works. I asked if it was possible to obtain a solution withour using DISTINCT

Comment: Without distinct it will be v hard to rewrite the query as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

have you tried writing the condition a2.ip = a.ip outside the subquery.?
i.e. in the where clause of outer query!

Comment: it doesn't make a lot of sense. In fact the table a2 in unknown in the external where

Comment: @marcosh ..please refer my latest answer!!